# Mysql, insertion in trigger inserting NULL values while shouldn't

Tags: mysql, keycloak

The logic is to add a row in a table in another DB when a row is inserted in the Keycloak user table.(simple enough I guess)
What happened was only the Key has value but the rest were NULL inserted (they do have values , they were all correctly inserted in KeyCloak table before the trigger happened)

Caesar had the same problem but it did not work with his solution.
[MySQL "After Insert" Trigger keeps inserting nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723533/mysql-after-insert-trigger-keeps-inserting-nulls)

I am using PHPMyAdmin for Mysql 
some code will be added automatically like "for each row..."

Name: add
Table: USER_ENTITY
Time: AFTER
Event: INSERT
Definition:

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO AnotherDB.application_user 
(`user_id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`hash`) VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.FIRST_NAME, 
NEW.LAST_NAME, md5(NEW.ID));

END
```

I expect the row inserted to be  ID , FIRST, LAST, HASH
But I get ID, NULL , NULL, HASH
So what is the cause for this problem?

**Edit June 21:**
thanks for the edits and suggestions. 
The target insertion table's creation sql is

```
CREATE TABLE `application_user` (. 
    `user_id` varchar(256) NOT NULL,  
    `type` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `first_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,  
    `last_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,  
    `group_id` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,  
    `wallet_id` varchar(256) NOT NULL,  
     PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`). 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1.
```

Keycloak's USER_ENTITY table is way longer but it could be where the problem is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `USER_ENTITY` (
  `ID` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL_CONSTRAINT` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EMAIL_VERIFIED` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `ENABLED` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `FEDERATION_LINK` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `REALM_ID` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_TIMESTAMP` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CLIENT_LINK` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOT_BEFORE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_DYKN684SL8UP1CRFEI6ECKHD7` (`REALM_ID`,`EMAIL_CONSTRAINT`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_RU8TT6T700S9V50BU18WS5HA6` (`REALM_ID`,`USERNAME`),
  KEY `IDX_USER_EMAIL` (`EMAIL`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And also I created this test table in a new DB and put in the same trigger, it works fine with both tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `SOMETHING` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The thing is I don't know what sql Keycloak will be executed when it receives a register request from its adapter and I can't reproduce the problem with my table.

Comment: execute`SHOW CREATE TABLE AnotherDB.application_user` and  other related tables in the question and paste the output(s) in the question by a edit..

Comment: Code should work. Please add table definitions for keycloak,application_user and all trigger code together with an insert to keycloak.

Comment: Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks all comments for making this better.

Answer (score 0):

OK...
It turns out to be something like this:

when Keycloak adds a row to that table, it tries to add a row with only ID(to test with UUID conflict?) first, then update to that row with full context.

So that trigger is correct in logic but it will only get the primary key back because there is nothing else there at the point of insertion.